# Find the volume of $G$ area which its upper bound is$u(x, \, y) = 16 + x^2$ , lower bound is $v(x, \, y) = 4 x +7 y$ , and side bound $x^2 + y^2 =1$.

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of $G$ area which it's upper bound is $u(x, \, y) = 16 + x^2$ , lower bound is $v(x, \, y) = 4 x + 7 y$ , and side bound $x^2 + y^2 =1$.

I denote $h(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1$.

I draw this in geogebra  I think the black line is the required volume but I don't know how to approach this problem ,any help please , thanks !

[image]

Comment: Use the upper and lower bounds to establish the limits of z, and the side bounds to find the limits for y and x and take a triple integral.

Comment: @DougM The limit of $z$ is $u $ and$ v$ but how i can find the limits for y and x ? is it $-\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$ ? Then the triple integral is $\int_0^1 dy \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-y^2}dx\int_{v(x,y)}^{u(x,y)}dz$ ? I TRY IT , BUT IT DOESNT CORRECT

Comment: y from -1 to 1.

Comment: Correct , thanks !